# Equivalent script of Datatable in angular ui grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have created a HTML with static data and export options.

```
plnkr.co/edit/n3cbx8GrGoJtOpgbxE32?p=preview
```

I am looking for the same set of options with static data in an Angular UI grid.

Could someone please help me with a code?

It is just a single HTML file which does the beauty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45407043, but cannot be closed due to the bounty.

Comment: Thanks, Brian and we can close this.

Comment: Answer is clearly explained by Brian. Please kindly check the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/45407043